# Proving a basis for a span(S)

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: If $S = \operatorname{span}\{(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in\mathbb{R}^3 \mid x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0\}$ and $B = \{(1, -1, 0), (0, 1, -1)\}$, prove $B$ is a basis for $S$.

What I've done so far:
Let $(x_1, x_2, x_3) = c_1(1, -1, 0) + c_2(0, 1, -1) = (c_1, -c_1 + c_2, c_2)$
then
$x_1 = c_1, x_2 = -c_1 + c_2$ and $x_3 = c_2$

substituting, I get $x_2 = -x_1 + x_3.$

I don't know if what I've done so far is right and if it is, where to go from here. the equation I made isn't the same as the equation in $S$. Does that mean $B$ is not a basis for $S$? Am I completely off?

Comment: @Cat : Notice my use of \operatorname{span} and of \mid, and that I put all math notation inside MathJax.  Those were my improvements on your proposed edit. $\qquad$

Comment: One can find the dimension of S to be 2, so all that's left to do is check that the basis vectors are linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

Any element in $(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in S$ satisfies $x_3 = -x_1-x_2$, and can therefore be written uniquely as $$(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (x_1,x_2,-x_1-x_2) = x_1(1,0,-1)+x_2(0,1,-1).$$

---

In general, $B = (v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ forms a basis for a vector space $V$ if and only if any $v \in V$ can be written uniquely as a linear combination of elements of $B$.

Indeed, suppose first that $B$ is a basis. Then because $B$ spans $V$, any $v \in V$ can be written as a linear combination of $B$. Furthermore, this is unique because if v = $\sum a_i v_i = \sum b_i v_i$ for some scalars $a_i,b_i$ then $\sum (a_i - b_i)v_i = 0$, whence $a_i - b_i = 0$ by linear independence.

Conversely, suppose every element of $V$ can be written uniquely as a linear combination of elements of $B$. Then in particular $B$ spans $V$. Moreover, $B$ is linearly independent because the dependence relation $\sum a_i v_i = 0$ implies that $a_i = 0$ by uniqueness of the decomposition of the zero vector.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but I'm still confused. I'm not sure how what you did shows that B is a basis for S.

Comment: @MaggyWood See my edit.